# QT NetworkAccessManager Unknown Error

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager, qtnetwork, qt-signals

I am trying to do a very simple REST client in QT however I am getting an "unknown error" in my Reply.
Also when I do a packet capture, I see 0 packets getting sent to the server.

My code is:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
 QNetworkAccessManager *NETWORK = new QNetworkAccessManager();
 NETWORK->setNetworkAccessible(QNetworkAccessManager::Accessible);
 QNetworkRequest REQUEST;
 REQUEST.setUrl(QUrl("http://test.com/test/rest/BOB"));
 QNetworkReply *REPLY = NETWORK->get(REQUEST);
 qDebug() << REPLY->errorString();
 return 0;
 }
```

and my result is: unknown error.

The simple Application does compile without errors or warnings.

can anybody see any issues?

My expected output is "Hello BOB" and was successfully tested with a PHP client using Curl.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be misusing the QtNetwork API. You have at least the following issues ongoing:

- You are including the whole QtNetwork module as opposed to the necessary classes.
- You call the errorStrin() before the error() signal is emitted. This is not good, and what you see is expected because the default state is UnknownError as per documentation.
- You are not connecting to the finished signal of the async API. The returned QNetworkReply is just a pointer that you can use later to access members, but it does not yet contain the reply that at that point.
- You are instantiating a QCoreApplication, but not actually using it for running an event loop which is necessary for the async operation for getting the reply. You could always block, too, but that is not really recommended most of the time.
- You are using a pointer for the QNetworkAccessManager here needlessly.
- You are using macro'ish uppercase letters for a regular variable name.

You could write some code like below. It would be simpler to use lambda with C++11, but I am assuming you need to get it work with pre-such compilers.

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkRequest>

#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QUrl>

class Download : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit Download(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject (parent) {}
        ~Download() {}

    public slots:
        // void handleFinished() {}
        void handleFinished(QNetworkReply* networkReply) { qDebug() << "Reply:" << networkReply->readAll(); QCoreApplication::quit(); }
        void handleError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError code) { qDebug() << "Error:" << code; QCoreApplication::quit(); }
};

#include "main.moc"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
     QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

     QNetworkAccessManager networkAccessManager;
     networkAccessManager.setNetworkAccessible(QNetworkAccessManager::Accessible);

     QNetworkRequest networkRequest;
     networkRequest.setUrl(QUrl("http://test.com/test/rest/BOB"));

     Download download;

     // QObject::connect(&networkRequest, SIGNAL(finished()), &download, SLOT(handleFinished()));
     QObject::connect(&networkAccessManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), &download, SLOT(handleFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

     // QObject::connect(&networkRequest, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)), &download, SLOT(handleError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));

     networkAccessManager.get(networkRequest);

     return a.exec();
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
QT = core network
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### Build and Run

```
qmake && make
```

Comment: Hi Laszlo, &Download is undeclared, what do I declare it as? (im fairly new with QT)

Comment: I tried to copy and replace my project (both main.pro and main.cpp) but now its saying "symbols not found for arch. x86_64". weird huh? those two files are the only thing in my project btw.

Comment: @user1873432: you are mixing up the architecture. Get the library with the arch you would like to build for.

Comment: Laszlo, it compiles fine with the previous code I made (although its not want I want of course). more info on the issue: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "vtable for Download", referenced from:
      Download::Download(QObject*) in main.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.  I'm using Mac so there is no 32-bit libraries to mix with in QT (at least thats what I think). Do you know how to avoid mixing libraries with thats the case?

Comment: @user1873432: you have not re-run qmake apparently. It is not that hard, really. :)

Comment: I have ran qMake but I still get the same error (I also did a rebuild as well just incase). Also I forgot to mention I had to comment #include main.moc because it doesn't exists.

Comment: @user1873432: Do NOT comment that. That is the whole point!! See? You are doing things wrong you do not mention, and you blame the code.

Comment: ok I uncomment and run a rebuild and now its working (thank you thank you!) but can you please explain why I needed to include main.moc? I never done this before.